# How can I use a variable to define MailAddress toAddress in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 aspx page from which I wish to send an email to the recipient specified in a text box named "supervisoremailTextBox". Is there any way that I can specify a variable as the recipient email address.  The code I have used which doesn't work is shown below:

```
MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("address@domain.co.uk", "Sender Name");
MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress("supervisoremailTextBox.Value");
message.From = fromAddress;
message.To.Add(toAddress);
```

Sorry if this a really dumb question and thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `MailAddress`, you need to use a valid email address.

The string `"supervisoremailTextBox.Value"` is **not** a valid email address.

If you mean to use the value of a textbox with the ID `supervisoremailTextBox`, use:

```
MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress(supervisoremailTextBox.Value);
```

Note that I have dropped the `"` to ensure you are not passing in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress(supervisoremailTextBox.Value);
```